# Right Datatype for react-icon

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a navbar with a custom type to use the map().
I'd like to have a icon for each entity so the icon is shown in the navbar in front of the text. My Problem is to find the right datatype to show the'icon' properly. I use different icons from the react icon library I already tried different types on it like React.ReactNode/ IconType/ string etc.

```html
export interface LinkDataType{
    title: string,
    path: string,
    icon:  IconType,
    cName: string
}

import React, { useState } from "react";
import {LinkDataType} from "../Types/CustomTypes"
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import * as FaIcons from "react-icons/fa";
import * as AiIcons from "react-icons/ai";
import * as GiIcons from "react-icons/gi";
import * as HiIcons from "react-icons/hi2";

import {AiFillHome} from "react-icons/ai";


 const  DataArray:LinkDataType[] =[
    {
title:"Home",
path: "/",

 icon: AiIcons.AiFillHome,
cName: "nav-text"
},
{
title:"Login",
path: "/login",
icon: AiIcons.AiOutlineLogin,
cName: "nav-text"
}, 
{
title:"PlacesOverView",
path: "/places",
icon: "<TbIcon.TbWorldPin/>",
cName: "nav-text"
},  
{
    title:"PlacesWithDetails",
    path: "/places/:id",
    icon: "<TbIcon.TbWorldSearch/>",
    cName: "nav-text"
    },  
    {
        title:"Register",
        path: "/register",
        icon: "<GiIcon.GiArchiveRegister/>",
        cName: "nav-text"
        }, 
     
] 
export default DataArray;

<nav>
        <ul>
          {DataForNavBar.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                <NavLink className="NavLink" to={item.path}>
                  {item.icon}
                  <span>{item.title}</span>
                </NavLink>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by using the `React.ComponentType` type for the icon property and render the icons as components.

Update your `LinkDataType` to use `React.ComponentType` like so:

```
export interface LinkDataType {
  title: string;
  path: string;
  icon: React.ComponentType;
  cName: string;
}
```

and then update your `DataArray` to use the imported icons as components:

```
import { AiFillHome, AiOutlineLogin } from "react-icons/ai";

     const DataArray: LinkDataType[] = [
      {
        title: "Home",
        path: "/",
        icon: AiFillHome,
        cName: "nav-text"
      },
      {
        title: "Login",
        path: "/login",
        icon: AiOutlineLogin,
        cName: "nav-text"
      },
```

Now you can render the icons as components

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    {DataArray.map((item, index) => {
      const IconComponent = item.icon; // Render the icon as a component
      return (
        <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
          <NavLink className="NavLink" to={item.path}>
            <IconComponent /> <----- Icon as component
            <span>{item.title}</span>
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope this will help you.